# Why are enumerations not separated by commas in "Storie dell'anno Mille"?

Tags: punctuation

I'm reading *[Storie dell'anno Mille](https://www.giunti.it/extracts/giunti/B09173/storie_dell_anno_mille_estratto.pdf)* by Tonino Guerra and Luigi Malerba.

The authors consistently don't use commas in enumerations:

> - Ti sbagli. Altro è morire in un letto con il materasso di lana e altro è morire annegato. Oppure scorticato infilzato bruciato strozzato scannato sbudellato. Oppure di fame di sete di febbre di lebbra, che ti venga la lebbra.
> - Anche la roba da mangiare tipo galline oche formaggio e altri animali?
> - … ma non aveva trovato niente, cioè soltanto ferraglia, lance spade alabarde e corazze ammaccate e coperte di polvere.

Otherwise, their punctuation doesn't seem off to me, except for this partucular quirk.

I thought it was some OCR error, but the [digitized images](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Storie_dell_anno_Mille/zMcJAQAAIAAJ?gbpv=1&bsq=alabarde) on Google Books from the original 1977 edition seem to lack the commas as well:

[image]

Is this orthography Guerra's own invention that is not used by other authors? Or is it some kind of pattern in Italian orthography, which is used by other authors, albeit rarely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non parlerei di regole, né  di un caso speciale, né di una innovazione stilistica dell’autore.

Nel caso della punteggiatura è difficile parlare di regole, o in genere di giusto o sbagliato, per lo più si tratta di consuetudini che variano nel tempo e soprattutto di scelte stilistiche dell'autore di un testo.

Nel caso dell’elenco sopra riportato nel brano di Tonino Guerra  si tratta di una scelta stilistica, ma non si può parlare di novità, pensando anche  a tutto quello che c’è stato nel ‘900, avanguardie comprese, italiane e non, che hanno fatto di tutto e di più.

Scrive ad esempio l’Accademia della Crusca:

> il Novecento è caratterizzato da una punteggiatura più in funzione
> ritmico-melodica, ma anche dalla sua completa assenza (si pensi ad un
> movimento letterario come il Futurismo). Come possiamo capire dal
> quadro qui brevemente delineato, il problema della punteggiatura in
> generale, e della virgola in particolare, è ed è sempre stato
> piuttosto complesso.
>
> Ma il fenomeno deve essere interpretato tenendo conto che la virgola è
> consigliata e, possiamo dire, attesa, all'interno di un dato testo
> solo in pochi casi, mentre più frequentemente viene utilizzata in
> contesti che non sono regolati da una vera e propria norma
> grammaticale ma dipendono piuttosto dal volere dello scrittore, che la
> interpreta a volte come una pausa intonativa, a volte come un
> separatore o ancora come una messa in evidenza di un soggetto.

https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/uso-della-virgola-prima-della-congiunzione-e/148

O si può vedere anche  l’intervista qui sotto, in cui si sottolinea come  “La punteggiatura non è una questione di sintassi, ma di comunicazione. Ed è difficile parlare di ‘errori’…

https://www.illibraio.it/news/saggistica/punteggiatura-errori-710456/

O ancora, a proposito specificamente degli elenchi:

> **"-Si usa, o almeno si può usare, la virgola: negli elenchi di nomi o aggettivi**, negli incisi (si può omettere, ma se si decide di usarla
> va sia prima sia dopo l'inciso); dopo un'apposizione o un vocativo e
> anche prima di quest'ultimo se non è in apertura di frase [...]"

in *La punteggiatura*  https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/la-punteggiatura/143

Quindi in un elenco, secondo quanto dice l’articolo *La punteggiatura*, la virgola è una scelta.

Dal punto divista stilistico l'assenza della virgola  nel brano di Tonino Guerra dà una idea di precipitazione, di agitazione, di accumulo di termini, nel discorso diretto del personaggio.

L'uso della virgola avrebbe reso il discorso più lento e solenne, forse anche un po' fuori luogo, visto il registro che va sul comico e sul colloquiale (mi pare, non ho letto il libro).

Per un esempio di elenco senza punti, tratto da testi delle avanguardie, posso citare da **Edoardo Sanguineti** nell’antologia *I novissimi*.  Qualche riga a caso, ma ce ne sono altre: “la nostra sapienza tollera tutte le guerre - tollera la peste mansueta delle discipline - la tua stanza mescola **pietre sirene pollici bruchi**…”. *I novissimi. Poesie per gli* *anni ‘60*, Einaudi, 1965, p. 105.

Per un **elenco solenne con virgole,** invece, mi viene in mente l'inizio del coro dell'*Adelchi* di **Alessandro Manzoni**:

*Dagli atrii muscosi, dai Fori cadenti,*

*Dai boschi, dall’arse fucine stridenti,*

*Dai solchi bagnati di servo sudor,*

*Un volgo disperso repente si desta;*

*Intende l’orecchio, solleva la testa*

*Percosso da novo crescente romor.*

Comment: @Charo, vedo che hai corretto l'apostrofo di ne' con l'accento, e hai ragione. Però vorrei solo dirti che è per me una scelta volontaria in alcuni casi usare l'apostrofo, che era accettato in passato nella tipografia, per il semplice motivo che vorrei che fosse ancora accettato senza troppi problemi nella comunicazione scritta non troppo formale, perché l'uso degli accenti a mio parere rende inutilmente lenta la digitazione, mi dà l'idea di pedanteria, quindi lo faccio apposta :-). Certo, non lo faccio se scrivo un romanzo. Lo so che è una battaglia persa...

Comment: Conosci qualche esempio della stessa punteggiatura in altri testi? In altre parole, si tratta di un'invenzione di Guerra o di uno schema di punteggiatura utilizzato da altri autori, anche se raramente?

Comment: Ce ne saranno tanti, sicuro niente di originale di Guerra, e niente di originale in genere, la citazione dell'Accademia della Crusca sopra menziona ad esempio il Futurismo. Se ho tempo cerco qualcosa e ti faccio sapere.

Comment: Un esempio, Ungaretti, con poesie in cui non c’è punteggiatura, ad esempio *Veglia*. “Non c’è punteggiatura, una caratteristica che Ungaretti mutua dalla poesia futurista e da poeti stranieri, su tutti Apollinaire”
https://library.weschool.com/lezione/giuseppe-ungaretti-veglia-analisi-commento-figure-retoriche-2550.html

Comment: O in Dino Buzzati, nell’incipit del racconto *Sciopero dei telefoni*, che intende riprodurre il parlato omettendo la punteggiatura: «Da principio udii due donne che parlavano, caso strano, di vestiti. “Niente
affatto io dico i patti erano chiari lei la gonna me la doveva consegnare giovedì e adesso
siamo a lunedì sera lo dico e la gonna non è ancora pronta e io sa che cosa faccio, cara la
mia signora Broggi io la gonna gliela lascio e se la metta lei se le accomoda!”»

Comment: Ok, metto Sanguineti nella risposta. Ma il caso di Buzzati mi sembra molto simile a Guerra, il primo esempio, nel senso di omettere la punteggiatura (una parte, anche Buzzati mette una virgola, ma fa lo stesso) per riprodurre il parlato.